# Iterate through Map to build dot notation chained methods in Groovy

Tags: groovy

The question talks about a specific library but the question applies to any chain of methods that requires iteration. The Nimbus JWT+JOSE library has a class called `JWTClaimsSet` which allows you to build a JWT with the following syntax:

```
        JWTClaimsSet jwtClaims = new JWTClaimsSet.Builder()
            .claim("claim1", "claim1")
            .claim("claim2", "claim2")
            .build()
```

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to programmatically add the claims. What I've tried so far is to create a class like this:

```
 static JSONObject GenerateJWT(Map mClaims){
    JWTClaimsSet jwtClaims = new JWTClaimsSet.Builder()


    mClaims.each {
        k,v ->
            jwtClaims = jwtClaims.claims(k.toString(),v.toString())
    }

    jwtClaims = jwtClaims.build()

    return jwtClaims.toJSONObject()

}
```

And call it like this:

```
MyClass.GenerateJWT(["claim1": "claim1", "claim2": "claim2"])
```

However, I get an error saying that (as indeed is the case):

> Cannot cast object 'com.nimbusds.jwt.JWTClaimsSet$Builder@12f9af83' with class 'com.nimbusds.jwt.JWTClaimsSet$Builder' to class 'com.nimbusds.jwt.JWTClaimsSet'

How can iterate through the map and set each item as claim, value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JWTClaimsSet` is a different class from `JWTClaimsSet.Builder` so your static typing is throwing it off here. All of the methods on the builder return a `Builder` object to allow for chaining *except* for `build()`, which returns the final `JWTClaimsSet`. I think this should work:

```
static JSONObject GenerateJWT(Map mClaims) {
    JWTClaimsSet.Builder jwtClaimsBuilder = new JWTClaimsSet.Builder()

    mClaims.each { k, v ->
        jwtClaimsBuilder = jwtClaimsBuilder.claim(k.toString(), v.toString())
    }

    JWTClaimsSet jwtClaims = jwtClaimsBuilder.build()

    return jwtClaims.toJSONObject()
}
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, thanks for taking the time to answer.